# Customization Crud Magento

Tags: php, magento

i want make simple customization crud, a data is send with my form, my form is show in page home and my form is validate an input from user when a user try to submit. when a user submit a post data will insert to my custom table. how can i do it with magento 1.7.

this my an example form

```
 <form>
        <p>
           <label>name</label>
           <input type='text' name='name'/>
        </p>
        <p>
         <label>email</label>
         <input type='text' name='email'/>
        </p>
       <input type='submit' value='send'/>
 </form>
```

Please help me i am very new with magento.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking here represent somehow the basics of a magento module for a custom entity.
For this you can try to mimic the behavior of a code module (cms pages or static blocks are the most simple, and products, categories & customers are a bit complex).
Or you can follow a tutorial for this. I found 2 in a few seconds.

- http://theblog.enova-tech.net/2011/09/create-custom-magento-module-tutorial/
- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/

Or you can use a module creator. There are a few out there:

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/utilities/developer-tools/ultimate-modulecreator-8949.html - this is mine, that's why I put it first :)
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/utilities/developer-tools/modulecreator.html - this is an other that helped me out through my junior period
- http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/ - this one has the advantage of beeing online so you don't have to install any extension.